# Test for convergence of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3}\ + \frac{2}{3 \cdot 5}\ + \frac{3}{5 \cdot 7}\ + \cdots$$

What is the $nth$ term here and what test should I use?

Comment: $\frac{k}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$

Comment: Ok then, comparing with $\frac{1}{n}$, the series is divergent?

Comment: To get to the point where you can use @Diya's suggestion, note that the per rlartiga's comment, the $n$th term is $\frac{n}{4n^2 - 1} > \frac{n}{4n^2} = \frac{1}{4n}$.

Comment: @Travis Or I can use limit form of the comparison test with $u_n=\frac{n}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$ and $v_n=\frac{1}{n}$ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term is given by $$a_n=\frac n{(2n-1)(2n+1)} = \frac n{4n^2 - 1} \gt \frac n{4n^2} = \frac 1{4n}\sim \frac 1n$$ Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{4n} = \frac 14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n$$ which diverges, just as the harmonic series with general term $\dfrac 1n$ diverges.

[Good to recall: If a series $\sum a_n$ diverges, then so does $\sum ca_n$ where $c$ is any non-zero constant.]

You can also use the limit comparison test, letting $$a_n = \dfrac n{4n^2 - 1}\;\text{ and }\;b_n = \dfrac 1n$$ to show divergence.